# How to replace rows of excel with rows from another data set

Tags: excel

I have an excel file like the following:

[image]

and I would like to replace the value of votes and avgsocre of those rows with Print = 1 with the rows I have in another file, which looks like the following:
[image]

The index number in the second file is exactly off by 1 and since there are also \N's  with values from rows with Print = 0, so I cannot use replace then vlookup.

Would appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the variables that I'll call `Design` and `Author` uniquely identify your observations, so it would probably make more sense to look up `Votes` and `AvgScore` based on those values rather than trying to use the `row-1` value in `col A` of the second file.

In your main file, make a column `Votes_new` with the formula (in this example, for `row 2707`):

`{=INDEX(SecondFile!$A$1:$H$11, MATCH(1, (SecondFile!$B$1:$B$11=$A2707)*(SecondFile!$C$1:$C$11=$B2707)*(SecondFile!$G$1:$G$11=1), 0), 4)}`

Use the same formula with `5` instead of `4` in the last argument in a column for `AvgScore_new`.

This formula matches on three criteria: `Design` (equal to the value in the current row), `Author` (equal to the value in the current row), and `Print` (equal to 1). It gets the value from the 4th column of the data in the second file, which is `Votes` (or the 5th column, which is `AvgScore`).

Note that you have to enter as an array formula using `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`.

Also note that this will return a `#N/A` error if there is no match (either because the `Design`-`Author` combination is not present or because `Print` is not equal to `1`) so you may want to enclose this in an `IFERROR()` formula.

---

Alternatively, if you *really* want to look up by row reference, you can use `=VLOOKUP(ROW()-1, ...)` to look up the current row (*e.g.*, `2707`) minus 1 (`2706`) from the second file, and then find the value of print: `=VLOOKUP(ROW()-1, SecondFile!$A1$H11, 7, FALSE)`. You can use this in an `IF()` function to look up a different column *if* the value is one: *e.g.*, `=IF(VLOOKUP(ROW()-1, SecondFile!$A1$H11, 7, FALSE)=1, VLOOKUP(ROW()-1, SecondFile!$A1$H11, 4, FALSE), "Value not found")`